# How to render .js.erb template and return JSON data

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, routes, rendering

I have some javascript that calls a URL mysite.com/articles.js which sends a request to the articles controller's index action. I need to return data to the javascript function in JSON format but before that, I want to update some partials on the page by rendering index.js.erb

I'm calling the URL via jquery

```
var url = '/articles.js

$.get(url, function(newItemData) {
  someOtherFunction(newItemData)
}
```

Is calling the URL w/ a .js ending not the same as sending an AJAX request (remote => true) ?? I have some other buttons and links that send ajax requests via remote => true and the .js.erb template is rendered automatically with that request. Is there a way to call the URL as an ajax request?

Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Correct me if I'm wrong, but it looks like you're trying to render two views from your controller: the `index.js.erb` file and a JSON response. That is not possible, as Rails only supports one `render`, `redirect_to` or `head` call.

That means you'll need to change your JavaScript code to send two requests: one to update the view (render `index.js.erb`) and another to return your JSON object.

Submitting a request to a `.js` ending URL is **not** the same as submitting an AJAX request. For that you'll need to set `remote: true`, as you mentioned, or build an AJAX request in you JavaScript code (`$.ajax()`, if you're using jQuery).

You may also consider taking a look at [Layouts and Rendering in Rails](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html).

Hope that helps!

Comment: I know that Rails only supports one render or redirect_to call her request, but the JSON data returned and the partials updated via the .js.erb template are built from the same dataset. It seems wasteful to  require two separate requests which will double the database retrievals. Any chance there's a better way for me to handle both in the same request? Thanks for your quick reply!

Comment: You're welcome! But still, you're trying to render two views (one `js.erb`, one `.json`). To avoid having two actions, you'll have to move the JSON handling to the `.js.erb` view or move the view update to the JavaScript code form where you make the request.